# Strapi GraphQL Where Null - Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, strapi

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
query {
    mediaitems(where: {approvedBy:  null}) {
        name
        media {
            url
        }
    }
}
```

The above should return non-approved `mediaitems`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"\" at path \"approvedBy\" for model \"Mediaitem\"
```

Note: `approvedBy` is a relation field to `user` model

Comment: Could you post mongoose/mongodb query instead of graphql's query

Comment: Actually query generation is handled by **strapi** I don't really want to modify any piece of its core ...